# Switch Statement for Banking System

Tags: c#, console, switch-statement, readline

Hi I'm new to this and I'm trying to figure out a way where the customer can input their chosen option from the DisplayMenu which then takes them to another screen like DisplayBalance() this is currently working. But then I want them to hit enter and return them back to the DisplayMenu() and be able to input another option to take them to another screen but currently what is happening is the console exits. Does anyone know how to fix this?

// Display Menu

```
private static void DisplayMenu()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to your online bank account\nPlease choose from the options below: ");
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("1.View Client Info");
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("2. View Account Balance:");
        Console.WriteLine("     2A.Everyday\n     2B.Investment\n     2C.Omni");
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("3.Deposit Funds:\n     3A.Everyday\n     3B.Investment\n     3C.Omni");
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("4.Withdraw Funds:\n     4A.Everyday\n     4B.Investment\n     4C.Omni");
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("5.View Everyday Banking Details");
        Console.WriteLine("6.View Investment Banking Details");
        Console.WriteLine("7.View Omni Banking details");
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("8.Exit");
    }
```

// Main

```
   private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       

        Client client = new Client("Tayla", "Brown", "027493922", "55 Grey Rd"); // Our one client

        Everyday everyday = new Everyday(client, Account.GenerateAccountNumber(), 2000m);
        Investment investment = new Investment(client, 500m);
        Omni omni = new Omni(client, 1000m);

      

            DisplayMenu();

            string userchoice = Console.ReadLine();//user input from menu options

            switch (userchoice.ToUpper())
            {
                case "1": // Display Client Info
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine(client.ClientInfo);
                    break;

                case "2A": // Display Everday Account Balance
                Console.Clear();
                DisplayBalance(everyday);
                    break;

                case "2B": // Display Investment Account Balance
                    Console.Clear();
                    DisplayBalance(investment);
                    break;

                case "2C": // Display Omni Account Balance
                    Console.Clear();
                    DisplayBalance(omni);
                    break;

                case "3A": // Everyday Account Deposit
                       
                    DepositAmount(everyday);
                    break;

                case "3B": // Investment Account Deposit

                    DepositAmount(investment);
                    break;

                case "3C": // Omni Account Deposit

                    DepositAmount(omni);
                    break;

                case "4A": // Everyday account Withdrawal
                          
                    WithdrawAmount(everyday);
                    break;

                case "4B": // Investment Account Withdrawal

                    WithdrawAmount(investment);
                    break;

                case "4C": // Omni Account Withdrawal

                    WithdrawAmount(omni);
                    break;

                case "5": // Everyday Details

                    DisplayDetails(everyday);
                    break;

                case "6": // Investment Details

                    DisplayDetails(investment);
                    break;

                case "7": // Omni Details

                    DisplayDetails(omni);
                    break;

                case "8": // Exit Banking

                    Console.WriteLine("You have chosen to exit the online banking. Thanks and come again!");
                   
                    break;
            default: // catch all, breaks the loop
                     //Console.Clear()
                break;
        }
        
    }
```

// Display Balance

```
   private static void DisplayBalance(Account account)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{account.AccountType} Balance: {account.Balance:$#,##0.00}");
        Console.ReadLine();
        DisplayMenu();
    }
```

Comment: The simplest solution is to place your switch block inside of a loop and have an exit option to bail from main.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`string userchoice = Console.ReadLine();` and all of the options below it need to be wrapped in an infinite loop i.e. `while (true) { ... }` . This makes it so once the `switch` statement breaks, the user is prompted for input again and the cycle continues. If you don't want to terminate with ctrl-C, you will have to move the terminating prompt to before the switch. For example:
`while (true) { string userchoice = Console.ReadLine(); if (userchoice == 8) { Console.WriteLine("You have chosen to exit the online banking. Thanks"); break; } else { switch ...`
**EDIT**: code with infinite loop

```
while (true) {
      string userchoice = Console.ReadLine();//user input from menu options

            switch (userchoice.ToUpper())
            {
                case "1": // Display Client Info
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine(client.ClientInfo);
                    break;

                case "2A": // Display Everday Account Balance
                Console.Clear();
                DisplayBalance(everyday);
                    break;

                case "2B": // Display Investment Account Balance
                    Console.Clear();
                    DisplayBalance(investment);
                    break;

                case "2C": // Display Omni Account Balance
                    Console.Clear();
                    DisplayBalance(omni);
                    break;

                case "3A": // Everyday Account Deposit
                       
                    DepositAmount(everyday);
                    break;

                case "3B": // Investment Account Deposit

                    DepositAmount(investment);
                    break;

                case "3C": // Omni Account Deposit

                    DepositAmount(omni);
                    break;

                case "4A": // Everyday account Withdrawal
                          
                    WithdrawAmount(everyday);
                    break;

                case "4B": // Investment Account Withdrawal

                    WithdrawAmount(investment);
                    break;

                case "4C": // Omni Account Withdrawal

                    WithdrawAmount(omni);
                    break;

                case "5": // Everyday Details

                    DisplayDetails(everyday);
                    break;

                case "6": // Investment Details

                    DisplayDetails(investment);
                    break;

                case "7": // Omni Details

                    DisplayDetails(omni);
                    break;

                case "8": // Exit Banking

                    Console.WriteLine("You have chosen to exit the online banking. Thanks and come again!");
                   
                    break;
            default: // catch all, breaks the loop
                     //Console.Clear()
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried this but now if I select for example 2a then it takes me to the correct screen but when I press enter nothing happens.

Comment: If you press enter without input, nothing is supposed to happen. Can you be a bit more descriptive as to what you mean?

Comment: When it takes me to the DisplayBalance() screen I want to be able to press enter then take me back to the DisplayMenu() screen where I can insert another option

Comment: I edited my answer to include what the loop should like. I can't understand why it isn't working for you as I believe everything seems correct.